# How to proceed with a definite integral of this form?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How do I find the definite integral of this sort of function?

$$ \int_m^n \frac{\sin(a  \sin(\sqrt{(b  \lfloor x\rfloor^2 + b  d + 1)}))}{a \sin(\sqrt{(b  \lfloor x\rfloor^2 + b  d + 1)})} dx  $$

This function is actually a form of the $ \operatorname{sinc} $ function except it has a floor variable nested inside it, and also takes the sine of another sine function.

Note: a & b = 10^k (a & b are higher order powers of 10)

Comment: $\int_0^x \operatorname{sinc}(t)\mathrm dt$ is already non-elementary. What makes you think you'll find a closed form for this?

Comment: @K.defaoite not necessarily a closed form but how to evaluate functions like this numerically, particularly when m = 0 and n = 10^20 for instance.

Comment: When $m=0$ and $n=10^{20}$ you may as well integrate on $(0,\infty)$.  The variable transformation $x\to \frac{z}{1-z}$ will change your integral from one on $(0,\infty)$ to one on $(0,1)$ which is numerically tractable by whatever method you wish, e.g Riemann sums, Gaussian quadrature, etc...

Comment: @K.defaoite  what about the floor variable nested within won't that affect the integral somewhat, seeing as floor variable integration tend to make require taking summations of the function?

Comment: @K.defaoite Also could you give me an example of this variable transformation with 
$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin(10^4  \sin(\sqrt{(10^8  \lfloor x\rfloor^2 + 10^8  31363 + 1)}))}{10^4 \sin(\sqrt{(10^8  \lfloor x\rfloor^2 + 10^8  31363 + 1)})} dx  $$

Comment: What's the context of this? Why is this definite integral important to you?

Comment: Looks wild, we'll probably need a lot of new special functions to give this a closed form but who knows

Comment: @K.defaoite Oh I need it to resolve a real world applied mathematical problem, it's basically a way for me to quickly figure out the existence of spikes/non noise data in a large batch of signal.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal I don't particularly nedd a closed form just a way to accurately calculate the definite integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_m^n \frac{\sin(a  \sin(\sqrt{(b  \lfloor x\rfloor^2 + b  d + 1)}))}{a \sin(\sqrt{(b  \lfloor x\rfloor^2 + b  d + 1)})} dx&=&\sum_{k=m}^n\int_k^{k+1} \frac{\sin(a  \sin(\sqrt{(b  k^2 + b  d + 1)}))}{a \sin(\sqrt{(b k^2 + b  d + 1)})} dx\\
&=&\sum_{k=m}^n \frac{\sin(a  \sin(\sqrt{(b  k^2 + b  d + 1)}))}{a \sin(\sqrt{(b k^2 + b  d + 1)})}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: This is actually interesting as I can then utilize the Euler McLaurin(integration) to resolve this summation to arbitrary accuracy.

Any Idea on how to numerically integrate the resulting function on the right hand though?

Comment: I am afraid I have no clue. Where is Ramanujan when you need him?

Comment: Lol, so true Ramanujan was the boss of finding closed form functions for various types of integrals.